# Regex with multiple condition for Octoparse

Tags: regex, web-crawler

I'm trying to extract a phone number(10 digits) from a crawled page. The phone number can begin with either 7 or 8 or 9 and is 10 digits long. So far ive been able to find the number starting with 7 .

```
7(.+?)\b
```

I want to find the number which starts with 7 or 8 or 9 and is 10 digits long. I'm trying to implement the regular expression in Octoparse. The input string is a HTML structure of a web page. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably

```
[7-9]\d{9}\b
```

Which is one of 7 to 9 followed by 9 digits. if `\d` isn't recognized by octoparse you can use `[0-9]`.

Comment: Thank you it worked . Is the regex for octoparse lingo different from that of the normal regex query ?

Comment: @prashantbana probably not, but there are some flavor differences in different languages.